# Wait for Task on UI Thread without producing a deadlock

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, task, deadlock

Keep in mind: I'm on .NET 4.0 and **can't use** the *async/await pattern* nor `.ConfigureAwait`.

I'm currently trying to keep the UI responsive while executing a longer-running operation, primary to be able to cancel the operation if needed.

Therefore, I've used `Task.Factory.StartNew` to start a new task on the UI Thread and `Wait` to wait for its completion.

It is important that the operation finished before I continue, that's why I used `Wait` to wait for its completion. 
However, this creates a deadlock on the UI thread.

Complete Code:

```
// currently on the UI thread
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => LongerOperation())
.ContinueWith(x =>
{
    // simple output that I'm done
}).Wait(); // -> deadlock. can't remove it, otherwise the app would continue
```

Calling that code looks like a normal function call

```
private void Run(){
    DoStuff();
    DoMoreStuff(); // it's important that DoStuff has finished, that's why removing .Wait won't work
}

private void DoStuff()
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => LongerOperation())
    .ContinueWith(x =>
    {
        // simple output that I'm done
    }).Wait();
}
```

How can I wait for the task to complete without creating a deadlock on the UI thread? Other answers suggest to use the async/await pattern but I'm not able to use that.

Comment: _"Keep in mind: I'm on .NET 4.0 and can't use the async/await pattern nor .ConfigureAwait."_  is there a way to use it anyway? @DmitryBychenko

Comment: @Fildor There is actually the option to use ```Microsoft.Bcl.Async```, still defeats the fact that I need it to work with native 4.0.

Comment: It's not deadlocking. It is blocking, which renders all the async senseless.

Comment: Are you even *sure* you are on .NET 4.0? It's not just that .NET 4.0 went out of support for several years now. All 4.x versions are binary replacements of the previous ones which means, unless you target Windows XP (also unsupported for several years) you are running on .NET 4.5 anyway - any installation or Windows update that installed 4.5 in the last *7* years would replace 4.0 with the new runtime

Comment: 1. Before `async-await`, `BackgroundWorker` was used for long-running tasks, you can use that. 2. Async -await can be used in .NET 4, check async-await bridge for earlier .NET versions

Comment: @delayedExtension if you insist on targeting an obsolete runtime, Microsoft.Bcl.Async is acceptable. You've already accepted a far higher risk, including a security risk. .NET 4.0 can't support TLS1.2, a minimum requirement nowadays. In any case, unless you target Windows XP (or a locked down, embedded machine) you *can't* target 4.0 even if you want to.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos Some of our customers still use application servers with .NET 4.0, upgrading is not an option and therefore backwards compatibility is needed.

Comment: @delayedExtension why? Again are you *sure* they haven't already upgraded, perhaps in the last 4-5 years? Do those servers *not* use TLS1.2? The only server that required .NET 4.0 was Windows Server 2003

Comment: @delayedExtension How big is your company in relation to your customers? And is that portion of customers critical?

Comment: @delayedExtension in any case, the way people updated the UI way back when wasn't BGW or BeginInvoke. Use `ContinueWith` with the TaskSchedulerOption to run on the UI

Comment: @Fildor Let's say that upgrading a server would cost the customer a lot of money as they can't continue working. Besides the .NET Framework Upgrade we would also have to upgrade a massive amount of software - which is simply too expensive and takes a lot of effort.

Comment: @delayedExtension I think you need `ContinueWith(...,TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext())`. Before you do that make **double extra certain** those servers don't run 4.5 already. Otherwise you'll pay for all the incompatibilities without any benefit

Comment: @delayedExtension let's say that the customer can't *NOT* upgrade without running afoul of GDPR, PCI and a mountain of other laws and regulations. What are they going to tell the court when they get breached? The "can't continue work" excuse won't be accepted in court because everyone can testify that installing an up-to-date runtime is easy.

Comment: @delayedExtension 1 Cent for each time I had _that_ discussion. The longer they wait, the more expensive it will be. **They will _never_ update.** Which is locking _you_ in. So, there are two Options: 1. Raise _your_ support fees astronomically, or 2. discontinue support for legacy systems.

Comment: @delayedExtension unless of course they intend to pass the blame to your company for not upgrading or patching their servers. This means you need good contract laywers and negotiators to avoid this, and/or a good criminal laywer on contract.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos Providing support for our software is part of our contract, upgrading is not. We advise to upgrade, but we can't force them. Besides that, the amount of server we have to manage is 4-digit, most of the time with custom adjustments. We can't just upgrade and hope we didn't break anything. It takes days to upgrade, and even longer to ensure that the software works and correctly interacts with the physical stuff that's out there. I surely wish it was easier, but it's not.

Comment: @delayedExtension I start to get the feeling this is an issue for Workplace SE. If I were you, I'd polish my CV ... this really sounds like a time-bomb.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you probaly *aren't* working on .NET 4.0 because .NET 4.x runtimes are binary replacements. Installing a .NET 4.5+ application or Windows Update patch means all applications now work on .NET 4.5 and later. Your development machine works on .NET 4.5+ at least, which means you already develop on a *different* runtime than the one you intend to target.

The only exception is if you target unsupported OS versions like Windows XP and Windows Server 2003, which never got .NET 4.5 support.

In any case, using [Microsoft.Bcl.Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/) *is* a viable option, as you've already accepted far greater risks, like running on 4.5 while targetting 4.0, or running on an unsupported OS that doesn't even have TLS1.2 support, a minimum requirement for most services nowadays, including Google, AWS, Azure, banks, payment gateways, airlines etc.

The other option is to use [ContinueWith](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.continuewith?view=netframework-4.8#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_ContinueWith_System_Action_System_Threading_Tasks_Task__System_Threading_Tasks_TaskScheduler_) with a `TaskScheduler` parameter that specifies where to run the continuation. [TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.fromcurrentsynchronizationcontext?view=netframework-4.8) specifies that the continuation will run on the original synchronization context. In a Winforms or WPF application, that's the UI thread.

Back then we used to write code like this:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => LongerOperation())
.ContinueWith(t =>
{
    textBox.Text=String.Format("The result is {0}",t.Result);
},TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

Handling exceptions and chaining multiple asynchronous operations takes extra work. `t.Result` will throw an exception if the task failed, so you need to check [Task.IsFaulted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.isfaulted?view=netframework-4.8) or [Task.IsCancelled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.iscanceled?view=netframework-4.8) before you try to use its value.

There's no way to short-circuit a chain of continuations with a simple `return` the way you can with .NET 4.5 and async/await. You can check the `IsFaulted` flag and avoid updating the UI, but you can't prevent the *next* continuation down the chain from executing.

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => LongerOperation())
    .ContinueWith(t=>
    {
        if (!t.IsFaulted)
        {
            return anotherLongOperation(t.Result);
        }
        else
        {
            //?? What do we do here?
            //Pass the buck further down.
            return Task.FromException(t.Exception);
        }
    })         
    .ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        //We probably need `Unwrap()` here. Can't remember
        var result=t.Unwrap().Result;
        textBox.Text=String.Format("The result is {0}",result);
    },TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

To stop execution in case of failure you'll have to use the [TaskContinuationOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcontinuationoptions?view=netframework-4.0) parameter and pass eg `NotOnFaulted`.

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => LongerOperation())
.ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        textBox.Text=String.Format("The result is {0}",t.Result);
    },
    CancellationToken.None,
    TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnFaulted,
    TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

What do you do if you want to end execution due to some business rule? You'll have to return *something* that all subsequent steps will need to forward to the end of the chain.

In the end, using `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` can result in far simpler code

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => LongerOperation())
.ContinueWith(t=>
{
    if (!t.IsFaulted)
    {
        var num=anotherLongOperation(t.Result);
        if (num<0)
        {
            //Now what?
            //Let's return a "magic" value
            return Task.FromResult(null);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //?? What do we do here?
        //Pass the buck further down.
        return Task.FromException(t.Exception);
    }
})         
.ContinueWith(t =>
{
    //This may need t.Result.Result
    if (!t.IsFaulted && t.Result!=null)
    {
        textBox.Text=String.Format("The result is {0}",t.Result);
    }
},TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

I'm not sure if continuations farther down need `Unwrap()` or not. They probably do, as the second step returns a `Task<T>`. Forgetting this can lead to hard-to-debug problems too.

Using `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` results in cleaner, simpler code that's far easier to get right :

```
public async Task DoRun()
{
    try
    {
        var x=await longOperation();
        var num=await anotherLongOperation(x);
        if(num<0)
        {
            return;
        }
        textBox.Text=String.Format("The result is {0}",num);
    }
    catch(Exception exc)
   {
      //Do something about it
   }
}
```

**Update**

As Stephen Cleary noted, BLC Async only worked with Visual Studio 2012. Which is also no longer supported and probably only available as a download for MSDN Subscribers.

Back in 2010 the Parallel team release some extensions and samples to make parallel and asynchronous processing easier, the [Parallel Extensions Extras](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ParExtSamples). That library included externsions like `Then` that made chaining and error handling a lot easier.

Most of these features are included in .NET itself since 4.5 so the samples and library weren't updated since 2011. Any NuGet packages or Github repos that claim to be the Parallel Extras simply clone and repackage this download.

That library *used* to be documented by [a series of articles by Stephen Toub](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/a-tour-of-parallelextensionsextras/) but Microsoft changed its blogging engine recently and the URLs of old migrated blog posts no longer work.

Since neither .NET 4.0 nor the Parallel Extras are supported, the links weren't fixed. Those articles are still available under [a different URL](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/author/toub/page/12/)

*"No longer supported"* means the docs, libraries and knowledge may be lost too. Some of the people that worked with tasks 7 years ago may remember the libraries and projects used back then, but 7 years is far too long.

Comment: Important note: **always** pass a `TaskScheduler` to both `StartNew` and `ContinueWith`. This avoids [problems with ambient task schedulers](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html).

Comment: I don't think it's possible to get `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` working these days. You need a *specific update* of an old version of VS, which I believe is no longer available for download. When I lost my build machine for AsyncEx, I spent months trying to recreate something that could use `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` with Silverlight, WinPhone, and all those old platforms. Eventually I just gave up and stopped supporting them.

Comment: @StephenCleary and the Pfx team blog posts from that era were probably lost or mangled in Microsoft's blog engine migration, along with the posts documenting how to use the Parallel Extension Extras.

Answer (score 0):

Try [MSDN: Backgroundworker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker?view=netframework-4.8). You can cancel your task by doing `backgroundworkerObject.CancelAsync();` if you have done `backgroundWorkerObject.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;` in the form's constructor.
This executes your long operation in a seperate thread without causing a deadlock in your UI.